# MLE of $f(x\vert\theta)=1/\theta$, $x_1 , \cdots , x_n \sim U(0,\theta) \;\;, \theta>0$,

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, uniform-distribution

## Original question

$x_1 , \cdots , x_n$ are independent random variables, identically distributed as 
a uniform distribution over $(0,\theta)$.

$$
f(x \vert \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}, \; 0<x<\theta, \;\; \theta >0
$$

What's the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for $\theta$.

## Comment on strict inequalities

(from olooney, edited slightly)

The MLE does not exist if we use strict inequality. But 
$x_i \sim U(0, \theta)$ has various definitions but makes the intent clear: to model the data as a uniform distribution. For a continuous p.d.f. any finite number of points has measure 0 and can be added or removed and the answer is "*almost surely*" (jargon for "with probability 1") the same.

Why not use a definition of the *U* which makes the MLE problem tractable and which is almost surely the same?

**Note that the question has strict inequalities, not weak**

[This is highlighted in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391631/137921)

## Other similar posts to this

Though I searched others have highlighted other posts of a similar nature :

[MLE for Uniform $(0,\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941187/mle-for-uniform-0-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How do you differentiate the likelihood function for the uniform distribution in finding the M.L.E.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Some derivations are shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49543/maximum-estimator-method-more-known-as-mle-of-a-uniform-distribution). I must admit I don't understand the need for Bayesian calculations here. The question doesn't seem to ask for Bayesian considerations. Could you clarify?

Comment: @COOLSerdash thanks, in that comment they've used the interval $0\leq x \leq \theta$, whereas it seems to be $0 < x < \theta$. Does having this closed interval change anything?

Comment: Why are you differentiating in the first place?

Comment: because I wasn't sure what to do with it, removed as those parts don't seem to be useful

Comment: Is this a homework question? In that case you should tag it as 'self-study'.

Comment: also note that this question has likely been asked several times before

Comment: Nothing came up on suggested and the one linked on math stack is both poorly answered, highly voted on, and now closed

Comment: There are many questions of similar form. The answer here should work for you https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/114378/164061

Comment: Well answered in these posts IMO: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941187/mle-for-uniform-0-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: From a measure theoretic viewpoint, which is all that matters, there is no difference between strict and weak inequality signs in the density of a $\mathcal{U}(0,\theta)$ distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an if you've anything not added in this post already that might be interesting to have as an answer. Someone has already remarked about measure though ( i think? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The p.d.f for one $x_i$ is given as

$$
f(x| \theta) = \begin{cases}
     \frac{1}{\theta} & & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \theta \\
     0 & & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let's call $\vec{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n)$.

The $n$ observations are i.i.d. so the likelihood of observing the $n$-vector $\vec{x} = (x_1, ... x_n)$ is the product of the component-wise probabilities. Ignoring the issue of support for the moment, note that this product can be simply written as a power:

$$
f(\vec{x}| \theta) =  \prod_i^n \frac{1}{\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta^n} = \theta^{-n}
$$

Next, we turn our attention to the support of this function. If any single component is outside its interval of support $(0, 1/\theta)$, then its contribution to this equation is a 0 factor, so the product of the whole will be zero. Therefore $f(\vec{x})$ only has support when *all* components are inside $(0, 1/\theta)$.

$$
f(\vec{x}| \theta) = \begin{cases}
  \theta^{-n} & & \text{if } \forall i, \ 0 \leq x_i \leq \theta \\
  0 & & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

By definition, this is also our likelihood:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta; \vec{x}) = f(\vec{x}| \theta) = \begin{cases}
  \theta^{-n} & & \text{if } \forall i, \ 0 \leq x_i \leq \theta \\
  0 & & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The MLE problem is to maximize $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\theta$. But because $\theta > 0$ (given in the title of the problem) then $\theta^{-n} > 0$ therefore 0 will never be the maximum. Thus, this is a constrained optimization problem:

$$
\hat{\theta} = \text{argmin}_\theta \,\, \theta^{-n} \text{ s.t. } \forall i \,\, 0 \leq x_i \leq \theta
$$

This is easy to solve as a special case so we don't need to talk about the simplex method but can present a more elementary argument. Let $t = \text{max} \,\, \{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Suppose we have a candidate solution $\theta_1 = t - \epsilon$. Then let $\theta_2 = t - \epsilon/2$. Clearly both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are on the interior of the feasible region. Furthermore we have $\theta_2 > \theta_1 \implies \theta_2^{-n} < \theta_2^{-n}$. Therefore $\theta_1$ is not at the minimum. We conclude that the minimum cannot be at *any* interior point and in particular must not be *strictly* less than $t$. Yet $t$ itself is in the feasible region, so it must be the minimum. Therefore,

$$\hat{\theta} = \text{max} \,\, \{x_1,..., x_n\}$$

is the maximum likelihood estimator.

Note that if any observed $x_i$ is less than 0, then $\mathcal{L}$ is a constant 0 and the optimization problem has no unique solution.

Comment: This answer is much nicer than a similar one on math stack, but I'm just wondering if you've used $0 \leq x \leq \theta$ instead of $0 < x< \theta$ on purpose? The original post has strict inequalities.

Comment: That difference is unimportant in practice, both intervals have probability 1 under the model.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen here it seems to be the difference between whether or not the MLE exists though. Are you suggesting that I should ignore that? That's not a loaded question, I'm not familiar enough with the material. Maybe considering strict inequalities here doesn't have much merit, thanks

Comment: @baxx, you are of right - the MLE does not exist if we use strict inequality. But you also wrote $x_i \sim U(0, \theta)$ which has various definitions but makes the intent clear: to model the data as a uniform distribution. For a continuous p.d.f. any finite number of points has measure 0 and can be added or removed and the answer is "almost surely" (jargon for "with probability 1") the same. Why not use a definition of the $U$ which makes the MLE problem tractable and which is almost surely the same?

Comment: @olooney fair enough, that seems reasonable. I've added that note to the OP as others might consider the answer an answer to a different question in a similar way to how I did. Hopefully it's alright for me to paraphrase your comment there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first consider the case when the question is read as stated. This is the approach I would recommend if asked this question when, say, taking a class in introductory theoretical statistics. Toy examples like this are commonly assigned as homework problems or on exams in such classes.

You can show (do it) that the likelihood function is
$$
 L(\theta) = \begin{cases} \theta^{-n} & \theta > x_{(n)} \\ 0 & \theta \leq x_{(n)}\end{cases},
$$
where $x_{(n)} = \max(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. The maximum likelihood estimate (MLE), if it exists, is the $\theta \in (0, \infty)$ that maximizes $L(\theta)$. In this case, since the inequality $\theta > x_{(n)}$ is strict, **the MLE does not exist**. Indeed, for any $\theta' > x_{(n)}$, the likelihood can always be increased by moving slightly to the left. However, you cannot pick as your MLE $\hat{\theta} = x_{(n)}$ since $L(x_{(n)}) = 0$. Clearly, no points to the left of $x_{(n)}$ can be the MLE either since the likelihood vanishes there.

Now let us also deal with the case where the question is interpreted differently. If you are free to pick which density for the $U(0, \theta)$ distribution to consider, i.e. you do not have to use the one given in the question, then it makes sense to pick the the density $f(x\mid \theta) = \theta^{-1}$, $0 \leq x \leq \theta$, instead. Recall, (Lebesgue) densities are only unique up to changes on sets of Lebesgue measure zero, so this is a density for the same distribution. With this density, the MLE exists and is equal to $\hat{\theta} = x_{(n)}$ which is easy to prove by noting that the likelihood is strictly decreasing on $[x_{(n)}, \infty)$.

Comment: yes, $L(\theta)  = 1/\theta^n$. We want to maximise this, so that we would choose the lowest possible value of $\theta$. The lowest possible value of $\theta$ that will include all possible values of $x$ is $x_{max}$, so we should say that the MLE of $\theta$ is $x_{max}$. 

I'm not sure if I'm getting mixed up with the inequalities though.

Comment: You are, that's exactly what my answer says. You have $L(x_{(1)}) = 0$, so it cannot be the MLE, right? You need to be more careful when you state what the likelihood is.

Comment: seems that it's enough to just say that as the inequality is strict there's no maximum so the MLE doesn't exist

Comment: What if instead of saying MLE doesn't exist, I say that mle of $\theta$ is $\sup (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom That would be incorrect, because $\sup(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \max(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. The MLE does not exist as the question is stated, contrary to what the accepted answer claims. This is easy to prove. In fact, I have given this question in several classes to students (which is about the only setting I can think of right now where toy examples like this are practically relevant).

Comment: @baxx I notice you have now added comments to the answer suggesting that you are equally interested in the case with weak inequality, is that right? If so, I can delete my answer.

Comment: @AnonYmous in the comments it's been said that the case with weak inequalities is valid for an example with strict inequalities. I don't have enough experience to refute this, but that's what I've been told by others. If you don't agree with that I think explaining why not would have value

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am not sure what $\max x_i$ and $\sup x_i$ mean. You said $\sup(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, which is equal to $\max(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ since the supremum and maximum of a finite set agree.

Comment: @baxx I added an explanation of why I think the difference is important.

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed in [the answer by Anon Ymous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391631/7224), the discussion on whether or not using the strict inequality is not pertinent [from a measure theoretic point of view](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211965/measure-theoretic-definition-of-mle): the definition of a $\mathcal U$$(0,1)$ distribution is one of a probability measure against the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ that gives any open interval within $[0,1]$ a probability proportional to its length:$$\mathbb{P}_\theta[U\in(a,b)]\propto b-a$$
This distribution being absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure, it enjoys a density$\frac{\text{d}\mathbb{P}_\theta}{\text{d}\lambda}$ that is constant almost everywhere on $[0,\theta]$. Hence
$$f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}\mathbb I_{(0,\theta)}(x)\quad\text{and}\quad f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}\mathbb I_{[0,\theta]}(x)$$
are two equivalent versions of the density of the *same* distribution. In such instances, the MLE will exist for some versions and not for others, which requires the selection of a smooth version of the density and hence of the likelihood function that allows for a solution. This is obviously a drawback of the MLE approach. (A similar difficulty arises with the Bayesian MAP which further depends on the definition of the dominating measure over the parameter space.)