# Maximum Likelihood Estimator : special case of uniform which exclude the upper limit

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, uniform-distribution, estimators

**I would like to understand why we can't get a MLE in this special case of PDF :**

"Sometimes it is not so easy to find the maximum of the likelihood function as in the examples above and one might have to do it numerically. Also, MLE does not always exist. Here is an example: let us consider uniform distribution $U[0, \theta)$ and define the density by
$$
f(x \mid \theta)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{\theta}, & 0 \leq x<\theta \\
0, & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
The difference is that we 'excluded' the point $\theta$ by setting $f(\theta \mid \theta)=0 .$ Then the likelihood function is
$$
\varphi(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f\left(X_{i} \mid \theta\right)=\frac{1}{\theta^{n}} I\left(\max \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)<\theta\right)
$$
and the maximum at the point $\hat{\theta}=\max \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ is not achieved. Of course, this is an artificial example that shows that sometimes one needs to be careful."

Indeed, it is always possible to take $\hat{\theta}=X_{n}$ since the $\text{$\log\mathcal{L}$}$ is decreasing, isn't it ?

Caution, this is slightly different from my previous post since I exclude the upper limit in PDF :

$$\frac{1}{\theta} = 0 \leq x<\theta$$

What is the trick to conclude about no existent $\hat{\theta}$ given a dataset $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ ?

Any help is welcome

**EDIT 1:** I found this answer particulary well explained for classical uniform case :

" The p.d.f for one $x_{i}$ is given as
$$
f(x \mid \theta)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{\theta} & \text { if } 0 \leq x \leq \theta \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Let's call $\vec{x}=\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)$
The $n$ observations are i.i.d. so the likelihood of observing the $n$ -vector $\vec{x}=\left(x_{1}, \ldots x_{n}\right)$ is the product of the component-wise probabilities. Ignoring the issue of support for the moment, note that this product can be simply written as a power:
$$
f(\vec{x} \mid \theta)=\prod_{i}^{n} \frac{1}{\theta}=\frac{1}{\theta^{n}}=\theta^{-n}
$$
Next, we turn our attention to the support of this function. If any single component is outside its interval of support $(0,1 / \theta),$ then its contribution to this equation is a 0 factor, so the product of the whole will be zero. Therefore $f(\vec{x})$ only has support when all components are inside $(0,1 / \theta)$
$$
f(\vec{x} \mid \theta)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\theta^{-n} & \text { if } \forall i, 0 \leq x_{i} \leq \theta \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
By definition, this is also our likelihood:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta ; \vec{x})=f(\vec{x} \mid \theta)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\theta^{-n} & \text { if } \forall i, 0 \leq x_{i} \leq \theta \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
The MLE problem is to maximize $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\theta$. But because $\theta>0$ (given in the title of the problem) then $\theta^{-n}>0$ therefore 0 will never be the maximum. Thus, this is a constrained optimization problem:
$$
\hat{\theta}=\operatorname{argmin}_{\theta} \theta^{-n} \text { s.t. } \forall i 0 \leq x_{i} \leq \theta
$$
This is easy to solve as a special case so we don't need to talk about the simplex method but can present a more elementary argument. Let $t=\max \left\{x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right\}$. Suppose we have a candidate solution $\theta_{1}=t-\epsilon .$ Then let $\theta_{2}=t-\epsilon / 2 .$ Clearly both $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are on the interior of the feasible region. Furthermore we have $\theta_{2}>\theta_{1} \Longrightarrow \theta_{2}^{-n}<\theta_{2}^{-n} .$ Therefore $\theta_{1}$ is not at the minimum. We conclude that the minimum cannot be at any interior point and in particular must not be strictly less than $t$. Yet $t$ itself is in the feasible region, so it must be the minimum. Therefore,
$$
\hat{\theta}=\max \left\{x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right\}
$$
is the maximum likelihood estimator.
Note that if any observed $x_{i}$ is less than $0,$ then $\mathcal{L}$ is a constant 0 and the optimization problem has no unique solution."

**Now, I have to understand the impossible existence of a MLE when we have strict inequality, i.e :
$$f(x \mid \theta)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{\theta}, & 0 \leq x<\theta \\
0, & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.$$
From my first track, it seems that we can't have in the same time an estimator $\theta=t-\epsilon$ strictly lower than $\theta$ and respecting :
$$\hat{\theta}=t-\epsilon=\operatorname{argmin}_{\theta} \theta^{-n}$$
But it is yet approximative in my mind.**

**EDIT 2:** Just a figure to better understand the 2 different cases (upper limit included or not) :

[image: Illustration of a MLE existence with upper limit included]

Comment: This may be due that the fact that between 2 randoms of PDF values or in general, I won't get the same maximum, will I ?

Comment: The explanation as provided is clear: by setting the likelihood to be zero when $\theta\le X_{(n)}$, there is no maximiser found within the open set $(X_{(n)},+\infty)$ for the simple reason that, for any $\theta\in(X_{(n)},+\infty)$, one can find a smaller $\theta^\prime\in(X_{(n)},+\infty)$ with a larger likelihood. From a probabilistic viewpoint, this example is borderline wrong as a density function $f(\cdot|\theta)$ is defined almost everywhere and hence $f(\theta|\theta)$ can be set to be equal to $1/\theta$ to avoid the paradox.

Comment: Apart from formal description given above by @Xi'an, you can think like this also: there should be non-zero probability that your estimate $\hat{\theta}$ is actually same as $\theta$. But in your case if you do take $\hat{\theta} = X_{(n)}$ then $\theta$ can never be same as this because the realized observation can never be equal to $\theta$ as it is not in the support of this rv. In other words, if a possible candidate has zero probability of actually being equal to the parameter. It is as good as any absurd estimate. So it's isn't really an estimate at all

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/391612/119261

Comment: @Dayne: whatever the representation of the Uniform density, the probability that $X_{(n)}$ is equal to $\theta$ is zero. There is therefore a zero probability that $\hat\theta=\theta$ whatever the continuous distribution of the $X_i$'s. _It is not a matter of support:_ $(0,\theta)$ or $[0,\theta]$ face the same impossibility that $\hat\theta=\theta$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Thank you for the pointer, I had forgotten [I had already answered this question in the past](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392611/7224).

Comment: @Xi'an: true but the intuition I was appealing to I guess should hold. When $\hat{\theta}=X_{(n)}$, the support of the rv $\hat{\theta}$ would not have $\theta$. If an estimate's support doesn't have the parameter it is supposed to estimate, it is bound to fail in hypothesis testing. I think i should have written that hypothesis that $\theta = \hat{\theta}$ is bound to be rejected outright. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Dayne: I do not get the point, as $X_{(n)}$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$, making it hard to reject its use, even though $nX_{(n)}/(n-1}$ can be considered to be superior...

Comment: @henripetit: the added text in bold is considering a different perspective from the earlier part of the question. The maximal observation $X_{(n)}$ is always available, always strictly less than $\theta$ and can serve as a converging estimator of $\theta$. Obviously, a different sample produces a different realisation of $X_{(n)}$, hence a different estimate, but this is a feature common to most statistical settings. Estimators are random variables.

Comment: @Xi'an: It is interesting if $X_{(n)}$ is a consistent estimator. I was just thinking that if we know that an estimator is bound to be rejected (with p-value of 1) in the hypothesis testing, for every possible sample, then would be fair at all to even call it an estimate of the parameter?

Comment: The quotation is incorrect, because the support of this distribution is $[0,\theta],$ not $(0,\theta).$  (By *definition* the support is a closed set.)

Comment: @Xi'an . Thanks for your answers. Could you take a look at my **EDIT1** and **EDIT2** ? for me, it seems to be reasonable to take $\hat{\theta}=X_{(n)}$ for both cases (including $\theta$ bound version and excluding $\theta$ bound version). Could you tell me why, in excluding $\theta$ bound version, $\hat{\theta}=X_{(n)}$ won't be a right MLE ? Is this because it won't be fixed at each random samples generated and so would depend of the random sample ? Regards

Comment: The point is 100% about maths: there is no minimum value over the open interval $(x_{(n)},\infty)$.

Comment: @Xi'an. You mean the interval $]x_{(n)},+\infty[$ ?